# What is this design and how can I analyze it?

Tags: repeated-measures, experiment-design, crossover-study

```
|                              Time=1                      |                          Time=2                        |                         Time=3                         |                         Time=4                         |
|--------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|
|        | Condition | Question       | Alice  | Bernard   |      | Condition | Question       | Alice  | Bernard   |      | Condition | Question       | Alice  | Bernard   |      | Condition | Question       | Alice  | Bernard   |
| Group1 | 1         | 1              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 17             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 33             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 49             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 2              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 18             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 34             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 50             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 3              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 19             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 35             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 51             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 4              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 20             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 36             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 52             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 5              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 21             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 37             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 53             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 6              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 22             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 38             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 54             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 7              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 23             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 39             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 55             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 8              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 24             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 40             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 56             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 9              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 25             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 41             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 57             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 10             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 26             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 42             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 58             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 11             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 27             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 43             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 59             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 12             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 28             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 44             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 60             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 13             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 29             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 45             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 61             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 14             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 30             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 46             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 62             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 15             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 31             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 47             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 63             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 16             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 32             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 48             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 64             | .      | .         |
|--------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|
|        |           |                | Cathy  | Dennis    |      |           |                | Cathy  | Dennis    |      |           |                | Cathy  | Dennis    |      |           |                | Cathy  | Dennis    |
| Group2 | 2         | 1              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 17             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 33             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 49             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 2              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 18             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 34             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 50             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 3              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 19             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 35             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 51             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 4              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 20             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 36             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 52             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 5              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 21             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 37             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 53             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 6              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 22             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 38             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 54             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 7              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 23             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 39             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 55             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 8              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 24             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 40             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 56             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 9              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 25             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 41             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 57             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 10             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 26             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 42             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 58             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 11             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 27             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 43             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 59             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 12             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 28             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 44             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 60             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 13             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 29             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 45             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 61             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 14             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 30             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 46             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 62             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 15             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 31             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 47             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 63             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 16             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 32             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 48             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 64             | .      | .         |
|--------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|
|        |           |                | Eric   | Fellicity |      |           |                | Eric   | Fellicity |      |           |                | Eric   | Fellicity |      |           |                | Eric   | Fellicity |
| Group3 | 3         | 1              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 17             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 33             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 49             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 2              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 18             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 34             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 50             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 3              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 19             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 35             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 51             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 4              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 20             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 36             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 52             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 5              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 21             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 37             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 53             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 6              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 22             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 38             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 54             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 7              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 23             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 39             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 55             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 8              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 24             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 40             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 56             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 9              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 25             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 41             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 57             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 10             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 26             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 42             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 58             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 11             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 27             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 43             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 59             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 12             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 28             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 44             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 60             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 13             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 29             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 45             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 61             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 14             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 30             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 46             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 62             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 15             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 31             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 47             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 63             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 16             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 32             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 48             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 64             | .      | .         |
|--------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|------|-----------|----------------|--------|-----------|
|        |           |                | Gordon | Helen     |      |           |                | Gordon | Helen     |      |           |                | Gordon | Helen     |      |           |                | Gordon | Helen     |
| Group4 | 4         | 1              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 17             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 33             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 49             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 2              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 18             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 34             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 50             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 3              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 19             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 35             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 51             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 4              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 20             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 36             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 52             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 5              | .      | .         |      | 2         | 21             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 37             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 53             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 6              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 22             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 38             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 54             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 7              | .      | .         |      | 4         | 23             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 39             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 55             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 8              | .      | .         |      | 1         | 24             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 40             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 56             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 9              | .      | .         |      | 3         | 25             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 41             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 57             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 10             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 26             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 42             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 58             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 11             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 27             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 43             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 59             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 12             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 28             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 44             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 60             | .      | .         |
|        | 3         | 13             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 29             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 45             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 61             | .      | .         |
|        | 4         | 14             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 30             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 46             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 62             | .      | .         |
|        | 1         | 15             | .      | .         |      | 2         | 31             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 47             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 63             | .      | .         |
|        | 2         | 16             | .      | .         |      | 3         | 32             | .      | .         |      | 4         | 48             | .      | .         |      | 1         | 64             | .      | .         |
```

There are two main factors of interest: Condition and Question. Observations are made at four Time points. Subjects are assigned to one of four Groups. (For now, assume two Subjects per Group as given above). Condition has four levels. Question is nested within Run and has 16 levels per Time (so the levels of Question vary across Time, but are constant across Groups for a given Time). Obviously the Subjects are nested within Group. The Condition-Question combinations have been made to ensure that no Subject answers the same Question more than once. Moreover, these combinations have been made in such a way that within each Time, every Condition-Question combination (64 in all) occurs, but split equally across the four Groups. (This splitting is necessary to ensure that every C-Q combination occurs, but no Subject receives the same Question more than once).

How can this design be analyzed? There are a number of complicating factors here: (i) There are repeated measures due to Subjects both within Groups and across Time. (ii) Within a Group and Time, not every Condition-Question combination occurs. This is because of the restriction that a Subject cannot see the same question twice. Due to this, the design seems to have a "fractional" quality about it.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to analyze? What is your objective?